# Processing a BZIP string/file in Scala

Tags: java, scala, bzip2

I'm punishing myself a bit by doing the python challenges series in Scala.

Now, one of the challenges is to read in a string that's been compressed using the bzip algorithm and output the result.

```
BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084
```

Now, after some digging it appears as if there isn't a standard java library for bzip processing, but there is something in the apache ant project, [that this guy](http://www.kohsuke.org/bzip2/) has kindly taken out for use as a separate library.

The thing is, I can't seem to get it to work with the following code, it just hangs in the scala REPL and the JVM maxes out at 100% CPU usage

This is the code I'm trying...

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream}
import org.apache.tools.bzip2.{CBZip2InputStream}
import org.apache.commons.io.{IOUtils}
object ChallengeEight extends Application {
    val inputString = """BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084"""
    val inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( inputString.getBytes("UTF-8") ) //convert string to inputstream
    inputStream.skip(2) //skip the 'BZ' part at the start
    val bzipInputStream = new CBZip2InputStream(inputStream)  //hangs here....
    val result = IOUtils.toString(bzipInputStream, "UTF-8");
    println(result)
}
```

Anyone got any ideas? Or is the `CBZip2InputStream` class expecting some extra bytes that you might find in a file that has been zipped with `bzip2`?

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT** For the record this is the python solution

```
import bz2

un = "BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!" \
     "\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084"

print [bz2.decompress(elt) for elt in (un)]
```

Comment: My standard behavior in such circumstances: Ctrl+F8, Shift+F9, F7, F7, F7, F7.... down to singularity point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape characters use a [unicode escape sequence](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100850) like `\uXXXX` syntax where XXXX is the hexadecimal sequence for the unicode character.

```
val un = "BZh91AY&SYA\u00af\u0082\r\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0080\u0002\u00c0\u0002\u0000 \u0000!\u009ah3M\u0007<]\u00c9\u0014\u00e1BA\u0006\u00be\u00084"
```

Comment: That seems to get further than before (it doesn't hang) but I get an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18002` when I run the code. Any ideas?

Comment: It works if you exchange the first UTF-8 conversion for a ISO-8859-1; like this: "val inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( inputString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") )". However this is more by chance I believe; in the JVM strings are strings and binaries are byte-arrays. There are many traps when trying to hold binary data as strings.

Comment: Oh good god, thank you man, this worked a treat! I understand that this really isn't the best way to go about things, but I've been pulling my hair out for ages trying to solve this stupid challenge!

Answer (score 0):

You are enclosing your string in triple quotes which means you will pass the literal characters to the algorithm rather than the control/binary characters they represent.

Comment: Putting the string in single quotes just throws a load of `error: invalid escape character` errors when you attempt to compile!